# Python, How to divide a data-frame in two new data-frames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

## I am want to split these dataframe into two new data frames.

#### 1) contains all the google

#### 2) contains all the bing

by matching strings works.. but by finding anything that starts with with "Bing" or "Google" will be even better!!

```py
 
Dataframe:
  
   number   platform         rds

0  200      BingBrand         56
1  200      BingNonBrand      56
2  200      BingNonBrand      56
3  151      GoogleNonBrand    56
4  1651     GoogleDisplay     56     
5  626      Bing              56
6  626      BingNonBrand      56
7  125      GoogleBrand       56



# It is working but only for the last condition in the brackets, 
example: BingBrand, GoogleBrand
 

# creating two new dataframes for each

cw_bing = cw[cw["platform"] == ('Bing' and 'BingNonBrand' and 'BingBrand' )]

cw_google = cw[cw["platform"] == ('GoogleNonBrand'and 'GoogleDisplay' 
and 'Google' and 'GoogleBrand')]
```

Trying to split by any row started with "Bing" or "Google"

```py
# Doesnt work

# cw_bing = cw[cw["vendorname"].filter(regex='Bing.*')]
# cw_google = cw[cw["vendorname"].filter(regex='Google.*')]
```

Final result should be like this

```
df 1 = 

            BingBrand         56
1  200      BingNonBrand      56
2  200      BingNonBrand      56
5  626      Bing              56
6  626      BingNonBrand      56

df2 = 

3  151      GoogleNonBrand    56
4  1651     GoogleDisplay     56     
7  125      GoogleBrand       56
```

Comment: Great! work perfect. thanks for the help Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use contain.

`bing = df[df.platform.str.contains('Bing')]`

`google = df[df.platform.str.contains('Google')]`

Comment: Great! work perfect. thanks for the help Michael